# "Update modified date" not enabled by default

Tags: episerver

This is more of a question on the Update Modified Date as given below.
Why does Episerver has this default setting as unchecked? I understand with saving content frequently it makes no sense to update Modified date but that shouldn't be the case when publishing content.
[image: Before]
[image: After checking Update Modified Date checkbox]

So the question is:

1- Why is it defaulted to be not updated even on published event?

2- If I have to change the setting, I have to explicitly go to each individual content & check the property(refer image 2). Is there any setting to enable it globally. Also ,what are the implications to the existing items when we enable this setting globally? More like is it advisable to do that? If not ,is there any alternatives to this?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: If you want, you could attach an event handler for the `Publishing` event to determine whether the content's modified date should be updated without the editor having to check that checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ted. I get that with proper event handling I could achieve that. However, I am trying to understand why that is not updated by default & if I do so i.e make the default as checked, what's the implication of changing this. As for the editor's knowledge, if we look at this from the editor's perspective, since the content is modified, the modified date should be updated too which isn't happening & so the editor has to explicitly go & check the property.

Comment: For CMS 11, there was a setting `uIDefaultValueForSetChangedOnPublish` to control default behavior for this. For CMS 12, it is not supported anymore. It is considered a "business logic" decision (= manual choice by editor) to update or not update modified date when you are changing content. Like Ted's saying in his answer, you can use `Saved` date to show the latest save date, if that's what your business logic needs. In short - `Saved` = automatic last change time, `Changed` = manual choice only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `Changed` property is only updated when the checkbox is checked.

The idea is for the web editor to make a conscious decision as to whether a change actually constitutes a content update (for example for an article where the "last updated" date is displayed on the page).

If the web editor just changes a typo, the content wouldn't necessarily be considered updated.

You still have a separate `Saved` property if you're just interested in when the page version was saved, regardless of whether it was considered *changed* or not.

`Changed` property: https://world.optimizely.com/csclasslibraries/cms/EPiServer.Core.PageData?version=12#EPiServer_Core_PageData_Changed

`Saved` property:
https://world.optimizely.com/csclasslibraries/cms/EPiServer.Core.PageData?version=12#EPiServer_Core_PageData_Saved